# "unityengine.component does not contain a definition for GetEnumerator" Error in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

/*
   Ihitable in the foreach loop is taken from the IHitable interface so I'm not sure if i have implemented it correctly 
*/

```
public interface IHitable
{

    void Hit();
}
```

/*
   Getting Error with second foreach loop as shown in the Title not sure how to fix the error
*/

```
   void Attack2()
    {
        var hits = Physics.OverlapSphere(AttackPoint.position, 0.5f);

        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            var hitables = hit.GetComponent(typeof(IHitable));

            if (hitables == null)
                   return;

           foreach(IHitable hitable in hitables)
                hitable.Hit();

            Debug.Log(hit.name);
        }
    }
```

// Any help suggestions would be really appreciated

Comment: hit.GetComponent(typeof(IHitable)) is returning only one object, and not a list/array, and does not implement IEnumerable, thus not implementing GetEnumerator as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `GetComponent` method is used to retrieve a unity component. A component is a class that derives from [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html). So the type that you give to `GetComponent` must derive from MonoBehaviour.

Maybe you should create a `Hitable` class that derives from `MonoBehaviour`, and add it to all of your hitable `GameObject`s.